# How to stop Google from revoking my refresh token?

Tags: api, token, refresh

In their "OAuth 2.0 Playground" tool, Google states the following:

Note: The OAuth Playground will automatically revoke refresh tokens after 24h. You can avoid this by specifying your own application OAuth credentials using the Configuration panel.

It's not clear what my "application OAuth credentials" are and where the Configuration panel is.

Where do I find these?

Answer (score 4):

So in order to do this, when you are enabling the api access and getting your client id and client secret, you'll see an area to put in an Authorized redirect URL, put in https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground there. Then in the OAuth playground the configuration panel is the cog in the upper right, select that and select Use your own OAuth credentials, then fill out your client id and client secret. That should prevent the Refresh Token from being revoked.